# Lua require not working

Tags: lua

I am trying to make one lua file require another. I am following this guide: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

My basic test, which should be a trivial hello world, does not work, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a console log which shows all files and all errors:

```
C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest

11/15/2017  03:03 PM    <DIR>          .
11/15/2017  03:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/15/2017  02:53 PM    <DIR>          Bar
11/15/2017  03:04 PM                92 BazModule.lua
11/15/2017  02:53 PM    <DIR>          Foo
11/15/2017  03:08 PM               139 main.lua
               2 File(s)            231 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  253,774,073,856 bytes free

C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest>lua main.lua
lua: main.lua:1: module 'BazModule' not found:
        no field package.preload['BazModule']
        no file 'C:\dev\LuaDist\bin'
        no file '.\BazModule.dll'
        no file 'C:\dev\LuaDist\bin\..\lib\lua\BazModule.dll'
        no file 'C:\dev\LuaDist\bin\..\lib\lua\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        main.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?

C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest>type main.lua
local baz = require("BazModule")
baz.Baz()

local bar = require("Bar.BarModule")
bar.Bar()

local foo = require("Foo.FooModule")
foo.Foo()

C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest>type BazModule.lua
local BazModule = {}

function BazModule.Baz()
    print("Hello Baz!")
end

return BazModule

C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest>lua -v
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

The expected output should be

```
Hello Baz!
Hello Bar!
Hello Foo!
```

But it can't find any of the files adjacent to main.lua and I don't understand why.

Comment: I tried an alternate main.lua:

    local baz = module("BazModule", package.seeall)
    baz.Baz()
    local bar = module("Bar.BarModule", package.seeall)
    bar.Bar()
    local foo = module("Foo.FooModule", package.seeall)
    foo.Foo()

==== This produced this alternate error output that didn't work:====

    C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\LuaTest>lua main.lua
    lua: main.lua:4: attempt to index local 'baz' (a nil value)
    stack traceback:
            main.lua:4: in main chunk
            [C]: ?

Comment: next time just google "lua module not found"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`require`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require) searches in directories listed in [`package.path`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) (for Lua files) and `package.cpath` (for compiled libraries).

Your error message…

```
lua: main.lua:1: module 'BazModule' not found:
        no field package.preload['BazModule']
        no file 'C:\dev\LuaDist\bin'
        no file '.\BazModule.dll'
        no file 'C:\dev\LuaDist\bin\..\lib\lua\BazModule.dll'
        no file 'C:\dev\LuaDist\bin\..\lib\lua\loadall.dll'
```

indicates the paths that `require` searched in.  It seems that `package.path` is *completely empty*, or maybe there's a single malformed path pattern in there. (Which would be `C:\dev\LuaDist\bin`.)

The [way the search for a module `foo.bar` works](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath) is that `?` is substituted by `foo/bar` (or `foo\bar` – depending on OS) and so `./?.lua` would find `./foo/bar.lua`.

So the way to fix this is to (a) fix the place where you (or something that you installed) are/is mangling the `package.path` ([via environment variable, startup script](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7), …?) and/or (b) add the current directory to the search path.

Comment: This seems like useful information, but I'm dumber than that. I never intentionally set or changed my package.path. How do I reset it back to the default?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I get it. I defined an environment variable called LUA_PATH, which I then added to my windows PATH variable as %LUA_PATH%, to get lua.exe to run anywhere from cmd. I did not realize this would change the behavior of lua. I need to rename the variable. THANKS!!!

Comment: I can confirm renaming LUA_PATH to LUA_EXE_PATH fixed my issue. THANKS!