# require function can't see the module file

Tags: lua

So this is my kek13 lua chunk file:

```
-- modules
-- a package is a collection of modules

local test = {}

function test.add(n1, n2) -- dont put local as the scope of this function 
since you already added
-- a local to the 'test' table... doing so will return an error
return n1 + n2
end

function test.hi(name)
return "my name is " .. name
end

return test
```

.. and this is my kek13Part2Real lua chunk file:

```
 print("===========================")

 local dad = require("kek13")

 print(dad.hi("A"))

 print(dad.add(1, 5))

 print("==============================")

 require ("kek13")

 print(dad.hi("ur mum"))
 print(dad.add(2, 2))

 print("========================================")
```

**They are in the same folder, at least in the document folder.**
The only problem is that this causes an error. Something like lua can't find or see the file. I'm using Zerobrane IDE for this by the way.

Comment: something like...?? you realize messages can be copied on a computer? Please read [ask] and learn how to operate google

Comment: What a helpful site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua require not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318950/lua-require-not-working)

Comment: if you expect help you should at least bother copying the error message you're facing. that will increase the chances that you get an answer that solves your problem. it would also help to find existing answers as you are not the first person who gets that error message. imagine going to a doctor and telling him only "I am sick". you'll have to answer a lot of questions befor he'll know what's wrong with you and how to help. but you alread know all your symptoms so share them to spare everyone's time

Comment: The site is helpful, but you have to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require does not check the folder where the calling script is located it.

Use `dofile` with a path or add the folder containing the desired script to your `LUA_PATH` environment variable or append it to `package.path`

This is not how require works. Please read manuals...

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require